# Strtok_s и заполнение массива

Tags: массивы, c++, strtok

Добрый день, ув. форумчане.

Есть такой вот код:

```
int i, pr_length;
WCHAR separators[] = L", ";
WCHAR *token, *next_token, *massiv[100];
WCHAR mess[] = L"str1, str2, str3"; // три элемента
WCHAR buffer[100];

token = strtok_s(mess, separators, &next_token);
for(i = 0; token; token = strtok_s(NULL, separators, &next_token), i++)
{
    massiv[i] = token;
}

pr_length = sizeof(massiv)/sizeof(massiv[0]);
wsprintfW(buffer, L"%d", pr_length);
MessageBoxW(0, buffer,0,0);

ExitProcess(0);
```

Заклинило меня на участке подсчета кол-ва элементов массива. pr_length, по идее, должен составлять 3, но он составляет 100.
Каким образом, можно корректно подсчитать и занести в новый массив все разделенные слова? (чтобы этот массив, совмещал в себе только эти три элемента: типа `WCHAR *massiv[] = {L"str1", L"str2", L"str3"}`

Comment: IMHO если работаете с WCHAR, то надо использовать [wcstok_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Но я не увлекался бы расширениями Микрософт, а использовал posix функции.

Answer (score 1):

Так массив у вас и содержит 100 элементов, и после 3 (или сколько там будет токенов) там идет мусор. И длина вам уже известна из обьявления. Насколько я понял вам нужно узнать количество токенов - используйте или счетчик из цикла (фактически он уже есть) или при инициализации обнуляйте массив:
*massiv[100] = {0};
и делайте подсчет в цикле пока не 0
Ну и правильную функцию взять для токенизации